# Display issues with SVG viewer on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API (which is awesome!) to upload SVG content.  The main problem I have is that the labels on the SVG are displayed incorrectly when I open the file in Google Drive.  They appear much larger than they should.

Downloading the file and opening in Chrome looks fine.  I believe the same issue happens in Gmail preview.

Here is an example SVG file:  https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B16Q4tqg5T6QcDRzTE1LSmxMTE0

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems with the viewer and not due to the upload mechanism. Have you tried uploading the same file from the Drive UI? Do you get the same rendering issue?

Comment: Yes, we think the issue may be related to image conversion for drive preview app. I was able to convert correctly to PNG using batik Java api. Here is that code: http://goo.gl/dGHKJ

Comment: Any update on whether the Drive viewer will be corrected for SVG?

Answer (score 0):

The preview still misbehaves and completely garbles the SVG when the google drive renders it. As reported earlier it is ok when downloaded and viewed locally with Chrome. (I also like to get this fixed).

Comment: Specifically, it displays the text of the svg rather than the image.  As such, technically, it isn't garbled, but perfectly displayed... in exactly the wrong way.  Heh.

Comment: Still the case in July 2023 (showing it as ascii instead of svg image in drive but ok when opened directly in Chrome) ... I guess Google is not going to fix this.